# Viber's sticker bought will be owned once or permanently?

Tags: viber-messenger

On my Android smartphone Google Samsung Galaxy, I install Viber app and intend to buy a sticker.

My question is whether I will have to re-buy the same sticker on another phone (using the same Google account of course) or it will automatically restored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stickers can be synced to other devices. So YES, it's permanent.

Source: [How do I sync my stickers across all devices?](http://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/1362371-viber-sticker-market-for-android)